# Simple string replacement set of rules

Tags: string, algorithm, replace

I have an application where users set up a bunch of objects by filling up a bunch of text boxes which represent values that these objects will take. Just like setting up a `Person` object which requires you to enter a `Name` and a `LastName` properties.

Now I want to introduce global variables that the user will be able to assign values to, or which's values will change during the execution of the program. And I want the user to be able to use them when filling up any object's properties. My first idea was to choose an special character that will mark the beginning of a variable name, and then let the user use the character itself twice to represent the character itself.

For instance, say I have a global variable called `McThing`. Then, say the symbol I choose to mark the beginning of a variable is `%`. The user would then be able to enter as a person's last name the string "Mc. %McThing", which then I'd replace using the value of `McThing`. If `McThing`'s value is "Donalds", the last name would become "Mc. Donalds".

The problem with this is that, if I'd have a variable called `He` and another called `Hello` and the user enters "%Hello" as the string I wouldn't know which variable needs to be replaced. I could change my rules to, for instance, use the "%" symbol to mark both the beginning and the end of the variable name. But I'm not sure whether this will cause any other problem.

What would be the simplest possible set of rules to achieve this such that the user will be able to represent every possible string without ambiguities? Ideally, the variable names can have any character but I could restrict their names to a given set of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of marking both beginning and end with `%` has one problem. What happens if the input string is `%foo%%bar%`? Do I get the value of `foo` and the value of `bar`? Or do I get the value of `foo%bar`? (Of course if `%` in variable names isn't allowed, this isn't a problem.)

The simplest way I can think of to avoid this problem is to use one symbol for the beginning and another (e.g. `#`) for the end. That should avoid any ambiguity. If the user wants a `#` in text or a variable name, he escapes it like so: `%#`. This causes no problems, since empty variable names are not a thing (at least I hope not).

Answer (score 0):

It will be fine and easy to implement on the assumptions that:

- You have no empty variable names  (i.e. if we see a `%%` is that a `%` or an empty variable name?)
- Variable names cannot contain `%`s (i.e. if we see a `%` in a variable name, is that the end or a `%`?)
  **OR**
  Variable names cannot start or end with `%` **and** you cannot have 2 variable names in a row
  (i.e. is `%a%%b%` = `a` and `b` or `a%b`?)

These assumptions will ensure that any `%%` always represents a `%` character, and any `%` always represents the start or the end of the string.

These assumptions might not necessarily be required, but at the very least they will make the implementation a lot more difficult (with the above assumptions, we never have to look more than 1 character forward).

**An alternative** with no such restrictions, loosely based on the way C/Java/etc. does it:

Have `%` take on a role similar to `\` in C/Java/etc. - use:

- `%s` to denote the start of the string
- `%e` to denote the end of the string
- `%%` to denote the `%` character

You can also use the same characters to represent the start and end, but, we may as well make them different so it's easier to read.